# invoke_result to obtain return type of template member function

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, invoke-result

How can I obtain the result type of a template member function?

The following minimal example illustrates the problem.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename U>
struct A {
};

struct B {
   template <typename F = int>
   A<F> f() { return A<F>{}; }

   using default_return_type = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(f)>;
};

int main()
{
    B::default_return_type x{};

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4edac6bf0866f2b6) on Coliru.

The code does not compile, giving error:

> main.cpp:11:63: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded
>   function
>
> 11 |    using default_return_type =
>   std::invoke_result_t;

What is the correct syntax to obtain the type of `B::f` with the template parameter `F` set to default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the return type like this:

```
using default_return_type = decltype(std::declval<B>().f());
```

Complete example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <typename U>
struct A {
};

struct B {
   template <typename F = int>
   A<F> f() { return A<F>{}; }

   using default_return_type = decltype(std::declval<B>().f());
};

int main()
{
    B::default_return_type x{};
    std::cout << std::is_same< B::default_return_type, A<int>>::value;
}
```

PS: It seems like clang and older gcc versions are not happy with `B` being an incomplete type and calling `f`. As a workaround, moving the `using` out of the class should help.

Comment: I've tried the same but I get "member access to incomplete type B"

Comment: @max66 which compiler?

Comment: @max66 hm interesting, it fails eg with gcc7.3.0  but is fine with gcc 9.2

Comment: Clang head 10.0.0.

Comment: Yes, I see that gcc (last versions) accept the code. The bad part is that I don't know who's right.

Comment: @max66 opened a new quesiton to clarify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268030/does-t-have-to-be-a-complete-type-to-be-used-in-stddeclvalt