# Does T have to be a complete type to be used in `std::declval<T>`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, incomplete-type, declval

Consider this example (coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59267843/4117728)):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <typename U>
struct A {
};

struct B {
   template <typename F = int>
   A<F> f() { return A<F>{}; }

   using default_return_type = decltype(std::declval<B>().f());
};

int main()
{
    B::default_return_type x{};
    std::cout << std::is_same< B::default_return_type, A<int>>::value;
}
```

It [compiles with no errors on gcc9.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/f15XHVHicLsXtBPF) but gcc7.2 and clang 10.0.0 complain about `B` not being complete. Clangs error is:

```
prog.cc:11:58: error: member access into incomplete type 'B'
   using default_return_type = decltype(std::declval<B>().f());
                                                         ^
prog.cc:7:8: note: definition of 'B' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct B {
       ^
prog.cc:16:8: error: no type named 'default_return_type' in 'B'
    B::default_return_type x{};
    ~~~^
prog.cc:17:35: error: no member named 'default_return_type' in 'B'
    std::cout << std::is_same< B::default_return_type, A<int>>::value;
                               ~~~^
```

Comment: The question title doesn't appear to match the error? To me, it looks like GCC complains about `.f()`. That makes sense; the incomplete type `B` doesn't have a member `f`.

Comment: @MSalters i thought the same, but then what is the real problem here? I would assume that once you got an instance from `std::declval` it doesnt matter anymore if the type was complete or not (and I guess I am wrong with that)

Comment: [expr.ref]/2 (C++11) says about class member access: _"For the first option (dot) the first expression shall have complete class type"_. And `B` is neither complete nor considered complete in _`alias-declaration`_.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I didnt find the sentence you quote, but only ["The class type shall be complete unless the class member access appears in the definition of that class"](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I wrote "C++11". https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ref#2. Nothing has changed in C++17 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#2.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer ok then I agree that my interpretation was off and it seems like something has changed since c++11 which makes the above ok in newer standards but not in c++11. Would you mind writing an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source of the error is not `std::declval`, but incomplete class member access.

Until the resolution of [CWG1836](http://wg21.link/CWG1836) [was merged](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/dbe0b33f1b11b91e54f3fe346b2ea36282ccfe1f) 2.5 years ago, the standard required the class to be complete in a class member access expression (`E1.E2`).
[[expr.ref]/2 in C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ref#2):

> For the first option (dot) the first expression shall have complete class type.

[[expr.ref]/2 in C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#2):

> For the first option (dot) the first expression shall be a glvalue having complete class type.

And a class is not regarded as complete in [*`alias-declaration`*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:alias-declaration) within its own [*`member-specification`*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#nt:member-specification).
[[class.mem]/6 in C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#6):

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type ([basic.types]) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, *noexcept-specifier*s, and default member initializers (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

Answer (score 8):

From [[declval]](http://eel.is/c++draft/declval#3):

> Remarks: The template parameter `T` of `declval` may be an incomplete type.

This wording has been present since C++11 (so it's not possible for compilers to be conforming to an earlier standard)

Comment: awesome, thats what I was hoping for. Seems like gcc got it fixed, clang not (yet)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: My first thought was that `T` should absolutely be a complete type. Glad I checked the standard.